# best practice fo function order when overloading a public method with a private one

Tags: c++

I was going to order my methods implementation according to the order in the class definition in the header file, that way I can clearly mark the public and private sections. But one of my methods has both  private and public overloads. It seems to me to be a bad idea to separate implementation of overloads of the same methods. what is considered best practice in this case?

EDIT:
some example code:

foo.h:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        void bar(int);
        void baz();
    private:
        void bar(somePrivateNestedClassOrWhatever);
}
```

foo.cpp option one:

```
/********* public *********/

void Foo::bar(int){...}
void Foo::baz(){...}

/********* private *********/

void Foo::bar(somePrivateNestedClassOrWhatever){...}
```

foo.cpp option two:

```
void Foo::bar(int){...}
void Foo::bar(somePrivateNestedClassOrWhatever){...}

void Foo::baz(){...}
```

Comment: overloads from base classes are hidden anyway, can you post a code sample so we can better understand the issue anyway?

Comment: There's no inheritance, just two versions of the same function, I'll add some example code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in .cpp (implementation) functions should be grouped by "what they do" and not "who can call them" (like in the header).

In your case, I'd prefer to move the private one near his similar, in the public "section" of the cpp (even if it is private), adding a comment "private overload" or something similar before the function.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you don't really have other choice.
It would be terrible if you would write something like:

```
public:
 method ();
 private:
 method (/*some parameter*/);
 public:
 //other public methods
 private:
 //other private methods
```

It's unreadable, i think the standard practice is to separate them.

Mostly there is 2 kind of user:
- Who want to use your class, in that case, he only care about public methods, not about the hidden private versions
- Who develope it. He will mostly work in the .cpp, where you can put these implementations together.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking about the order in the cpp file not the header.

Comment: Ohh, feel free to put them together in the .cpp, i think that's the standard practice.

Comment: but then it's unclear witch is private and witch is public...

Comment: You don't care about things like that in the .cpp
You search for callable functions in the header, in the .cpp, you search for HOW they do it.